# Displaying urls with case sensitivity

Tags: domains, url, case-sensitive

I just bought the domain name `http://www.startupsandfinance.com/`. During the registration process I tried to buy it like `http://www.StartupsandFinance.com/` but could not do that because they ignored it. Is there any way that the website can show up in the search results as `http://www.StartupsandFinance.com/` as it looks more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the [domain name system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) is case insensitive.

> Intercapping is often used to emphasize the meaning of a domain name.
>   However, DNS names are case-insensitive, and some names may be
>   misinterpreted in certain uses of capitalization, creating slurls. For
>   example: Who Represents, a database of artists and agents, chose
>   whorepresents.com, which can be misread as whore presents. Similarly,
>   a therapists' network is named therapistfinder.com. In such
>   situations, the proper meaning may be clarified by use of hyphens in
>   the domain name. For instance, Experts Exchange, a programmers'
>   discussion site, for a long time used expertsexchange.com, but
>   ultimately changed the name to experts-exchange.com.
>
> Intellectual property entrepreneur Leo Stoller threatened to sue the
>   owners of StealThisEmail.com on the basis that, when read as
>   stealthisemail.com, it infringed on claimed (but invalid) trademark
>   rights to the word "stealth".

Comment: I once bought a domain name, named `TECHNOLOGY ARENA.com`. In Google search results, it was the only domain who used to be displayed in all caps.

Comment: @www.AppTec.net Let me be clear, not only does Google not display URLs with case, the DNS system itself is *case insensitive*. The registrar didn't ignore your attempt register a domain with caps in it, it's that it simply isn't possible.

Comment: Experts Exchange never used that domain name. It did own it for quite a while, but it lapse several years ago. However, you're more than welcome to perpetuate the myth. Eric Peterson / Netminder Senior Administrator, Experts Exchange

Comment: Hello. Just read it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange#Trivia).

Comment: Funny that you don't know the history of your own site. Here's a link to the way back machine history of your site http://web.archive.org/web/20000622011822/http://expertsexchange.com/

Comment: It appears you were using it between 1999 and 2004

Comment: And here's the snopes entry http://www.snopes.com/business/names/domains.asp